# Bash problem: sed command to replace 'C:\Music' withe '~/Desktop/music'

Tags: bash, sed

### Input

I have a playlist files seems

```
#file 1: i.m3u
C:\Users\curlywei\Music\........\a.mp3
C:\Users\curlywei\Music\........\b.mp3
```

```
#file 2: j.m3u
C:\Users\curlywei\Music\........\x.mp3
```

Above files are in the same folder.

### Expect Output

```
#file 1: i.m3u
~/Desktop/Music/......./a.mp3
~/Desktop/Music/......./b.mp3
```

```
#file 2: j.m3u
~/Desktop/Music/......./x.mp3
```

### Command I do

```sh
for i in $(ls *.m3u| tr '\n' ' '); do sed 's#\#/#g' -e 's#C:/Users/curlywei/Music#~/Desktop/music#g' $i; done
```

### Actual result

```
#file 1: i.m3u
C:/Users/curlywei/Music/......../a.mp3
C:/Users/curlywei/Music/......../b.mp3
```

```
#file 2: j.m3u
C:/Users/curlywei/Music/......../x.mp3
```

Only `\` is replaced with `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```sh
for file in *.m3u; do
    printf "%s\n" '1,$s!/^C:\\Users\curlywei!~/Desktop!` '1,$s!\\!/!g' w | ed -s "$file"
done
```

---

For each file, open it with `ed` (The file editor, as opposed to the stream editor `sed`), and on each line, first replace the leading path, and then all backslashes with forward slashes, and finally save the file.

See [why `for f in $(ls *.mp3)` is wrong](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: Thanks! it's good experience about this problem for me!